# Viewpoint dependant deformation of objects in photos

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I have a question concerning the deformation of objects in photos. Which deformations can an object depicted on a photo undergo through viewpoint and condition changes?

Some deformations I have in mind are:

- rotation
- scale
- shearing
- translation
- illumination
- occlusion

Which deformations did I forget?

Best!

Comment: It there something like a paper discussing that?

Comment: Is shearing even possible in normal images of solid objects?

Comment: If you're panning a camera and it scans lines sequentially it could shear?

Comment: Ok but that's no usual scenario for taking pictures i guess

Answer (score 5):

Since you have listed "illumination", I am assuming that "condition changes" include changes in lighting.  So I would add cast shadows, which will change if you move the light source.

Also, all the geometric transformations you have listed are affine. But if you move the camera perspective changes as well. So you may want to consider the projective transformation.

Comment: yep forgot that one ;-)

Answer (score 1):

1. Noise, Filtering or any processing?
2. Cropping
3. Color conversions and brightness & contrast changes (inline with illumination but these are linear transformation).
4. smearing.
5. Flip or mirroring (not sure if this is possible)
6. Gamma corrections, if related to devices?

Any thing you can do with GIMP or Photoshop?!